# What security measures does Firestore Functions have by default to protect from API call floods?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am interested with Firebase functions. However, I'm wondering does Firebase function have means to limit API calls from a user?

If a rogue user/ex-employee wants to sabotage the app, can it abuse the functions by creating millions of API calls to hit the company with excessive bills?